# Camel - Persist Database connection inside a Processor

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to persist the database connection throughout the camel route. I have defined the Datasource called "stageDataSource" on the route. How do I use the same datasource or rather the same database connection in the Processor "MyDBStageProcessor"?

I created a new connection within the MyDBStageProcessor and closing it. But, it maxs out my connections in Postgres. Hence, I want to use a single connection across the whole route.

Can I get the Database connection from the Exchange object?

```
        .to("sql:select t.id, vsts_project_id from table_name ?dataSource=stageDataSource")
        .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true")
        .split(body())
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .setHeader("Authorization", simple("Basic "+encodedToken))
            .setHeader("Content-Type", simple("application/json"))
            .setHeader("Accept", simple("application/json"))
            .setHeader("project_id",simple("${body[vsts_project_id]}"))
            .setHeader("team_id",simple("${body[id]}"))
            .setBody().simple("${body[vsts_project_id]}/${body[id]}")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(vstsServerURL + "/" + vstsCollectionName + "/${body}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.0"))
            .to(vstsServerURL + "/" + vstsCollectionName + "/${body}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.0").convertBodyTo(String.class)
            //.to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true")
            .process(new MyDBStageProcessor())          
        .end()
        .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true");
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyDBStageProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside MyDBStageProcessor");
        String input = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
        //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(exchange.getIn().getBody());
        System.out.println("Body: " + input);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
        DataSource dataSource = DBCPDataSourceFactory.getDataSource(); 
        Connection dbconn = dataSource.getConnection(); //how to use the same connection from the Camel route?
        try {
         // do some db work
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            dbconn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not do this, better use connection pooling (hikari, c3p0, ...). With reusing single connection, you will have many problems - Connection object is not thread safe, Connection times out etc...

Comment: Thank you, @Bedla! I have changed my code to use hikari connection pooling and it seems to have resolved the issue. Please add it as an answer so that accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this, better use connection pooling (hikari, c3p0, ...). With reusing single connection, you will have many problems - Connection object is not thread safe, Connection times out etc.